# Is there a way to play a sound while loading other sounds in PyGame?

Tags: python, pygame, playback

I am playing a sound when the user clicks on a button to start loading a level.

I firstly did this:

```py
if event_received:
    play_the_sound()
    load_the_files()
```

But the sound playback stopped when the game loaded the files. I thought I needed to get the events, so I put `load_the_files()` into another thread while getting the events in the main thread.
But it still did the same.

I found nothing in the documentation.

After a little bit of research, I found that because I load other sound files in `load_the_files()`, PyGame stops the playback of the sound played. Is there a way to avoid this split of the sound?

Answer (score 0):

Are you loading sound or music?

For music:

```
pygame.mixer.music.load("YOUR MUSIC FILENAME HERE")
```

and to play it:

```
pygame.mixer.music.play(-1) # -1 loops the sound infinitely
```

and to stop it:

```
pygame.mixer.music.stop()
```

for sound:

```
pew = pygame.mixer.Sound("YOUR PEW SOUND FILE HERE")
```

and to play it:

```
pew.play()
```

Comment: I know, but I think this does not help me: even when playing the sound in the form of `pygame.mixer.music.play()`, it still gets stopped.

Comment: In my opinion I think the problem comes from PyGame, which stops any playback when it loads a sound file.